# Null item in Sitecore publishItem pipline processor

Tags: sitecore, publish, pipeline

I have a pipeline processor in the publishItem pipline that checks for a specific condition on a certain type if item. It’s been working fine for a while, but I recently just started seeing site publishes failing because of a null reference error.

In my code and found that my item object is null. This is how I get the item in the processor:

```
Item sourceItem = context.PublishHelper.GetSourceItem(context.ItemId);
```

I’m not checking if sourceItem is null, so it was a bug, which I fixed by checking for null before moving on. This solved the errors.

However, I’m confused as to how this could be. context.ItemId has a GUID, but GetSourceItem is returning null. If I search in Sitecore for the GUID I get no results. How can Sitecore be trying to publish an Item that doesn’t exist?

This is on a dev server and around this time, we were building some new templates and had created and deleted several templates, so I wonder if these items were ones that got deleted.

Comment: What type of publishing are you performing? The `History` table also tracks deletions. You could try to look up the ID in that table and check if it is one of the deleted items.

Comment: It's a full site smart publish. I'll check the history table, but if they're marked as deleted, why would they be being sent thought the publishing pipeline?

Comment: Not sure. But what happend  when you publish with related items on a item with broken links..

Comment: Not sure either. An Incremental Publish makes sense to send the ID through. Suggest you make publish, delete an item then make a another publish so you capture the ID. Might be less stuff to trawl through.